# O-N-O bond angles in oxides of nitrogen

Tags: physical-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, bond, molecular-structure

[image]

If we look at the bond angles of O-N-O in figure (c), (D) and (F), there not too much change in bond angle. Even though they are notable.

So my question is,

Why do we observe **very** small change in angles?

Comment: This seems to be two entirely separate questions so you should ask them as so.

Comment: 1. A simplistic explanation would be to say, that in all relevant oxides nitrogen exists in $sp^2$ hybridization state. The reason for it is that it have to form n+1 bonds with n atoms, forcing it to form a double bond, that requires it to adopt said hybridization. || 2. When one needs to quickly estimate geometry of a molecule, quantum chemistry calculation may help. For precise experimental measurements diffraction methods are suited, say X-ray diffraction for solid state and gas electron and gas neutron diffraction for gas phase.